# Combine expression functions in a global variable

Tags: apache-nifi

I'd like to create a global variable (ie at process group level) whose value is an expression function (a date in my example):

```
${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

Does NiFi allow that?

Note that this variable is shared across several processors, so it must be global. Manually changing its value to a specific day will allow me to do some reprocessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use NiFi expression language to create such variables.
For dates and formatting of dates, you can take a look at [the official documentation.](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates)

Then you could use an [UpdateAttribute processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/) where you define a variable ("test" in the example below) with the value you provided:

```
${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

[image: UpdateAttribute Properties]

which will result in a flow file with the parameter on the flow file. You can then access this parameter in all subsequent processors. You reference it as `${test}` to access its value. [image]

#### Global Variables

You can not use "dynamic" variables on a Processor Group (or root) level, since a change in the value of such variables requires a restart of the underlying processors that reference this variable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use a global variable, as it is shared across several processors

Comment: @dams, I added some info about global variables in my answer above.

Comment: Hmm, that's a pity ... I would allow some interesting use cases